# React redirect with extension not working

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to redirect an old URL to my new URL just in-case one of our users clicks an old URL, I want them to get to our new website not our old one.

***Simply this:*** 
`<Redirect from='/original-page.aspx' to='/original-page' />`

I've been searching the web for the last month now and I just cannot find a solution for such a simple task.

**Version**
react-router: Version 4.2.0
types/react-router: Version 4.0.26

**Steps to reproduce**
Adding this code to my routing file
`<Redirect from='/original-page.aspx' to='/original-page' />`

**Expected Behavior**
Page should simply redirect to `/original-page`

**Actual Behavior**
Page does not redirect
React breaks behaviour when it finds the period within the URL

**PLEASE HELP x-D**

Comment: Is your old URL and new URL on the same domain?

Comment: Yes they will be once live....

Comment: Did you use Redirect in Switch as specified by the doc here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect ?

Comment: Yes I did indeed I will see if I can update the question with some more detailed code